# Design of a system to measure the speed of a falling simulated raindrop

Tags: arduino, transistors, programming, infrared

I would like to know if using an IR emitter and a photo-transistor would do the job. Here are the specs of the [photo-transistor](http://job.http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/400/499826_DS.pdf).

Also I'm using the Arduino Uno board; any tips on how to program it would be much appreciated.

I have decided to use two IR led (38 kHz Pulse Generator with a 555 Timer) with the circuit as shown in this link http://www.trainelectronics.com/artcles/PulsedIR/index.htm . Also i'll be using 2 ir receivers( http://www.engineersgarage.com/sites/default/files/TSOP1738.pdf ).

Next step would be to calculate the time for the drop to calculate the time for the drop to travel from IR led 1 to IR led 2. So, i guess signal would be cut as the drop pass through the ir beam. I would like to know from the output of the receiver how to connect it to the arduino uno and what code would be suitable for this purpose? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more information to help you. What exactly are you trying to do and what have you done already?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear: what's a good sensor to measure the speed of a falling raindrop? The question doesn't define what "good" means, but I think it's safe to assume it means inexpensive, with an easy interface, and reasonably accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an IR LED as transmitter, and a phototransistor or photodiode sensitive to Infrared (and preferably not very sensitive to visible light) would work to detect raindrops or water drops passing between emitter and sensor.

If you need higher precision, a low power (1-2 mW) IR laser would work better as the emitter, properly aligned to the sensor.

For a detailed description of a suggested procedure that would yield less false-positives, see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/50938/14004), to a very similar question.

Comment: Also, does frequency of the IR laser be 38kHz or any toy laser would work?

Comment: If you are not too concerned about spurious light being picked up by the sensor, any toy laser and any phototransistor or photodiode would work fine. A toy red laser and a red LED used as a sensor would work, as well. Look up LEDs used as light sensors, on a search engine.